# Unable to solve an error while running Gridsearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to the realm of machine learning, and I started competing in Kaggle competitions to get some practical experience. I am competing in the knowledge competition CIFAR 10- Object Recognition in Images, where you have to classify thousands of images in 10 classes,all the data I use can be found there. I tried to implement Gridsearch to optimize the parameters of my machine learning algorithm, but whenever I try to fit my classifier with my training data I get an error. I have found the function that raised the error, and it has something to do with my labels not having the right type, but I have no clue on how to solve it. The Labels I use are strings, and I preprocess them so that I can feed them to the algorithm. Am I doing something wrong there? Or perhaps something goes wrong when I split the dataset for the grid search? Frankly, I lack the experience and knowledge to solve this problem, and I could definitely use your help.

**The code involved:**

```
import glob
import os
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cross_validation 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

def label_preprocessing(Labels):
    Labels = np.array(Labels)[:,1]
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit_transform(Labels)
    return Labels
def model_selection(train,Labels):
    parameters = {"C":[0.1,1,10,100],"gamma":[0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1]}
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(train, Labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
    svm = SVC()
    clf  = GridSearchCV(svm,parameters)
    clf  = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
    print ("20 fold cv score: ",np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf,X_test,y_test,cv = 10,scoring = "roc_auc")))
    return clf

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    train_images = np.array(file_open(image_dir1,"*.png"))[:100]
    test_images = np.array(file_open(image_dir2,"*.png"))[:100]
    Labels = label_preprocessing(pd.read_csv(image_dir3)[:100])
    train_set = [matrix_image(image) for image in train_images]
    test_set = [matrix_image(image) for image in test_images]
    train_set = np.array(train_set)
    test_set = np.array(test_set)

    print("selecting best model and evaluating it")
    svm = model_selection(train_set,Labels)
    print("predicting stuff")
    result = svm.predict(test_set)

    np.savetxt("submission.csv", result, fmt = "%s", delimiter = ",")
```

**full traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdc\workspace\final_submission\src\SVM.py", line 49, in <module>
    svm = model_selection(train_set,Labels)
  File "C:\Users\Abdc\workspace\final_submission\src\SVM.py", line 35, in model_selection
    clf  = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 707, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 493, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 517, in __call__
    self.dispatch(function, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 312, in dispatch
    job = ImmediateApply(func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.results = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\grid_search.py", line 311, in fit_grid_point
    this_score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 294, in score
    return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 1064, in accuracy_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_clf_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\metrics.py", line 123, in _check_clf_targets
    raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: unknown is not supported
```

**This is the function that raised the error. It can be found in the sklearn.metrics module:**

```
def _check_clf_targets(y_true, y_pred):
    """Check that y_true and y_pred belong to the same classification task

    This converts multiclass or binary types to a common shape, and raises a
    ValueError for a mix of multilabel and multiclass targets, a mix of
    multilabel formats, for the presence of continuous-valued or multioutput
    targets, or for targets of different lengths.

    Column vectors are squeezed to 1d.

    Parameters
    ----------
    y_true : array-like,

    y_pred : array-like

    Returns
    -------
    type_true : one of {'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences', \
                        'multiclass', 'binary'}
        The type of the true target data, as output by
        ``utils.multiclass.type_of_target``

    y_true : array or indicator matrix or sequence of sequences

    y_pred : array or indicator matrix or sequence of sequences
    """
    y_true, y_pred = check_arrays(y_true, y_pred, allow_lists=True)
    type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
    type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

    y_type = set([type_true, type_pred])
    if y_type == set(["binary", "multiclass"]):
        y_type = set(["multiclass"])

    if len(y_type) > 1:
        raise ValueError("Can't handle mix of {0} and {1}"
                         "".format(type_true, type_pred))

    # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed
    y_type = y_type.pop()

    # No metrics support "multiclass-multioutput" format
    if (y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator",
                       "multilabel-sequences"]):
        raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))

    if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:
        y_true = column_or_1d(y_true)
        y_pred = column_or_1d(y_pred)

    return y_type, y_true, y_pred
```

**Extra information about the Labels:**

**Content of labels and dtype:**

```
In [21]:
Labels = np.array(Labels)[:,1]
Labels


Out[21]:
array(['frog', 'truck', 'truck', ..., 'truck', 'automobile', 'automobile'], dtype=object)
```

**Content of labels after preprocessing**

```
In [25]:

Labels = np.array(Labels)[:,1]
Labels
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
Labels = le.fit_transform(Labels)
Labels



Out[25]:
array([6, 9, 9, ..., 9, 1, 1])
```

**Shape of labels after preprocessing:**

```
In [18]:
    Labels = np.array(Labels)[:,1]
    Labels.shape
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    Labels = le.fit_transform(Labels)
    Labels.shape

Out[18]:
(50000L,)
```

The original content can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/cifar-10/data. Which contains an ID for a datapoint and its class Label. So it is a nx2 matrix.

Comment: What is shape, dtype and content of ``Labels``?

Comment: The np.shape returns after preprocessing (5000L,), dtype = object and the content of the labels is strings of classes. The original content can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/cifar-10/data. Which contains an ID for a datapoint and its class Label. So it is a nx2 matrix.

Comment: Ok, wait, there problem is something else. What are you trying to do? The GridSearch searches for the best parameters and then is an estimator with the best found parameters. If you pass this estimator to ``cross_val_score`` it will **refit** it again!

Comment: I wanted to get the model with the best parameters using Gridsearch and then I wanted to evaluate that model with cross_val_score. But this is wrong? I tried to run the program without cross_val_score but I still get the same error.

Comment: Yes this is not what is happening. You need to use "clf.best_estimator_". Also I am not sure I would do it the way you do it. It seems a suboptimal way as you throw away all the previous training data when doing the cross-validation. This is not related to the error, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be caused by issue [#2374](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2374). As a workaround you can try to use `Labels = Labels.astype(str)`.

Also, I would suggest you to follow the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code conventions to share python code with the community. In particular variable names are usually lowercase.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was precisely the issue. Also thank you for reminding me of the importance of following conventions.

Comment: I am using `sklearn 0.16.1` and I tried this work around, but I still get an error when using rf classifier `ValueError: multiclass format is not supported` note that this only happens when I am using GridSearchCV. Any advice?